# bootstrap-datetimepicker: layout issues with input textbox and icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) in a form with a radio button, and I'm having a lot of issues with it. The first problem is that only the old version of it is working for me, not the current one, but that's okay (though I'd like to know why). The bigger problem is that the layout is messed up: the little square with the calendar icon is bigger that the input textbox, like this:
[image: screenshot]

I have several forms like this, and in some of them, the layout recovers when I replace the "name" attribute of the textbox with "id." That doesn't work for all forms though, and if I understand it correctly, I shouldn't use "id" with forms anyway. Taking it out completely also helps sometimes, but I need it to get the input for my form.
I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trj87ytj/66/) with my code, but it doesn't seem to work properly. Eonasdan's [sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/) is slightly different from mine.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
        <div class="textlikelabel">Question? *</div>
            <label><input value="answer1" type="radio" name="answers" required="required">Answer 1</label>
        </div>
       <div class="radio">
           <label><input value="answer2" type="radio" name="answers" required="required">Answer 2</label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio">
            <label><input value="answer3" type="radio" name="answers" required="required"/>Specific date:
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">                                                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="answer3text"/>
               <span class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
               </span>
            </div>
            </label>
        </div>                                        
</div> 
</div>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({                              
icons: {
time: "fa fa-clock-o",
date: "fa fa-calendar",
up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
} });
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?? I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid nesting the `input-group` inside of a `label` as well as the parent `radio` div. It is inheriting the undesired styling as a result.

```
<div class="radio">
    <label><input value="answer3" type="radio" name="answers" required="required" />Specific date:</label>
</div>
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="answer3text" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
```

Your JS fiddle also had a broken link to the font awesome css file

See: http://jsfiddle.net/spasticdonkey/1o3b3b1o/2/

Note you should be using the latest version of the datetimepicker script, no reason the older script should be working better for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I made the changes you suggested, but the only thing that changed is that the input textbox got longer. The layout is still messed up:( It's so weird because this part of the form is identical in all of my forms, except that sometimes it looks fine, and sometimes it doesn't!

Comment: oh and I have no clue why the newer version isn't working... it won't do anything when I click on the calendar icon.

Comment: sounds like there is still some invalid html and/or improperly nested elements; and possible JavaScript errors and/or file loading issues... but hard to say without seeing more of your code. I would verify all of your CSS and JS files exist in your development environment and have the correct file paths and load order. If you continue having issues, can you fork my fiddle with a larger segment of your html?

Comment: Okay, I went through the whole page and corrected invalid html using the w3 validator. The only thing that seems to influence it is changing "value" to "id." But what would I do without my value? Which CSS and JS files do I need?

Comment: I meant the name, not the value. Sorry!

Comment: I can fix it by putting it in a div with a new class and then specifically styling the input element and the input-group-addon class within that div... and I have to put !important behind everything. That feels like cheating.... What am I missing?